# ASP.NET Core and WebRTC for peer-to-peer video chat

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, webrtc

What I want to achieve is a POC where two user are chatting in peer-to-peer videocall using ASP.NET Core and WebRTC (if it is necessary SignalR).

[image: Mock screen]

I read a lot of [documentation](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#simple-peer-to-peer-example) about WebRTC and most of the example I found don't work because they show the old implementation of this protocol (for example this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_video_demo.htm)). Also, I saw this implementation on [Github](https://github.com/mgiuliani/webrtc-video-chat) but it is using `getUserMedia`. I got the same error if I use the latest version of `adapter.js`.

[image: error message]

I googled a bit and I found other examples like one article on [html5rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/): in this case the *indx.html* is working locally but if I deploy it on a server I get this error.

[image]

The last script I tried to use is [Simple Peer](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer).

The new and right way is, if I understood correctly, to use `RTCPeerConnection` and `RTCDataChannel`. I can't find a working example.

Comment: Hi . i have a same problem . can you help me ?

Answer (score 12):

A good example that work on. Net core 3.1 and javascript:
https://github.com/Shhzdmrz/SignalRCoreWebRTC

Working example with signalr core, ionic and peerjs:
https://dev.to/timsar2/ionic-video-call-by-peerjs-4fli

Working example with signalr core and angular:
https://dev.to/sebalr/video-call-with-webrtc-angular-and-asp-net-core-39hg

Answer (score 6):

The getusermedia is only available on websites secured with the https protocol or when running in localhost. If it is http the getusermedia is not available.

Working examples are indeed hard to find. I have [this github repository](https://github.com/Dirvann/webrtc-video-conference-simple-peer) which uses [simple-peer](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer), has a signaling server and can connect 2+ users together with video chat.
You can also try the [DEMO](https://dirvann-webrtc-video.herokuapp.com/) of the repository.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look. Is it working for iOS?

Comment: @Enrico Haven't tested it as I don't have an iPhone. But I don't see why it wouldn't work on IOS.